# Dojo: dynamically select checkbox

Tags: checkbox, dojo, dijit.form

I work with Dojo 1.11. Currently I'm having a ridicilously simple issue that I cannot solve. I have a dijit/form/CheckBox checkbox declared in my template like this:

```
<input name="realizationProcedureLock" id="realizationProcedure_lock_${id}" value="" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" data-dojo-attach-point="realizationProcedureLock" data-dojo-props="checked: false"/>
```

In my js template I want to uncheck it:

```
 on(this.importMonth, 'change', function () {
...
// uncheck the cb when changing months
this.realizationProcedureLock.checked = false;
...
}
```

This does not work although there is a checked property on this.realizationProcedureLock which changes when set. When this property is false and the checkbox is selected, hovering over the checkbox unselects it...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

change

`this.realizationProcedureLock.checked = false;`

to

`this.realizationProcedureLock.setAttribute('checked',false);`